# Child window access an array from parent window is not working in IE, but works in Firefox, how to fix?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I have a **index.html** page which has a button (`id="my-btn"`):

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>My INDEX PAGE</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br><input type="button" id="my-btn" value="OPEN NEW WINDOW"/>
        <script src="js/my.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The index page included **my.js** which is used to handle button click event, when button is clicked, a new browser window(child window) will be opened with a new page(**new.html**)

**js/my.js:**

```
$('#my-btn').click(function(){  
  var childWin = window.open('new.html', '');
  childWin.parentElements=[1,2,3];
});
```

**as you noticed above, I passed an array `[1,2,3]` to the new opened child window.**

The new page (**new.html**) opened in a new browser window(child window):

**new.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="my-arr"></div>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/new.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

In the new page, **new.js** is included which will append the text of the array passed from parent window as the content of this page in child window.

**js/new.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var arr= window.parentElements;

for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    var el = arr[i];
    $('#my-arr').append("<strong>"+el+"</strong>");
}

});
```

Everything is working in **Firefox** (I got the array in the new child window page).

**BUT** when I test it in **IE 7**, it does not work, in the new popped up page, IE shows an error =>**"Length" is null or not an object** which complain about "`elements.length`" in **new.js**. It seems IE does not support pass data in this way `childWin.parentElements=[1,2,3]`

How to make this code working in IE?

Comment: try with  `window.opener`, this will get you access to the parent window. For example, to refresh the parent window, you can do

`window.opener.location.refresh();`

Comment: @diEcho, could you please be more specific? where should I put window.opener? By the way, I do not need to refresh my parent window, why you suggest me this?

Comment: i write the line  `for example`. have u read that line??, you should use window.opener in child window. btw read the article i post as my answer for better way

Comment: @diEcho, as you noticed in my post, I use new.html as the child window page, but if I use window.opener, how can I custom the page to be used in child window?